# RM 2013 release fails because RM 2013 removes underscore

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am using Visual Studio 2013, TFS 2013 and Release Management 2013 update 3. I am using MSBuild for Build and Release purpose with ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xml template having MSBuild arguments "`/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false`"

The release is getting fail because RM is removing first "_" underscore in the build path due to which build release fails. It shows error as

> "package location
>   "\buildserver\DropFolder\smoke-web\smoke-web20170209\web" does not
>   exist or Deployer user does not access.
>
> RM is removing underscore from "smoke-web_20170209".

Comment: Did you use a component in your release template? How do you set the "Path to package" in the component?

Comment: Yes, I have used component in release template and have set source as "build with application" and deployment tool is "xcopy deployer".

Comment: What's the result if there isn't underscore character? Does it work fine?

Comment: yes. it works fine when I change all underscore with hyphen. One strange thing I noticed it that, the build works well on DEV stage environment and it fails on QA stage environment. The RM is not removing underscore on DEV but it is removing on QA stage environment

Comment: I have the same issue, but only on newer versions of Windows server. Works fine on 2012 R2, doesn't work on 2016. It seems to remove the first underscore it sees. I did the above and changed the build name to include a hyphen, but it still failed because of "_PublishedWebsites". Anyone else got a workaround that that?

Answer (score -1):

Check the complete source path for the xcopy on "Configure Apps > Components" If you're using UNC path you shoud input:

\\servername  \ [Build] \  folder

Hope this helps.